# Replacing a string with a new number based on the old one using regex

Tags: mysql, regex, perl, awk

I came up with this regex

```
[0-9]+:"https:\/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/
```

which matches on this data

```
...
21:"https://10.0.0.0/blah"
...
```

and what I want to end up with is

```
...
4:"blah"
...
```

where the amount subtracted was the length of the https:// part. The number to be subtracted is constant, i.e the IP address is always the same so I'm looking for some sort of substitution like this pseudo regex

```
s|[0-9]+:"https:\/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/|($1-17):"|g
```

where 17 is the length, but I am having trouble coming up with something that would perform this. I think I need one of those magical perl one liners. This data is all in a MySQL DB as well, so I could possibly do something right in SQL, but am not familiar enough with grouping options and whether arithmetic would be possible on it in SQL.

I also understand that regex's cannot do arithmetic (except for that magical one on SO)

Perhaps AWK is best suited for this? I have never used AWK before though so would need to do some reading

Comment: In Perl, the replacement expression can be Perl code: `s{...}{ ($1-21).':"' }e` (Similar functionality exists in other languages.)

Comment: Can you explain why 42 becomes 15?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, He wants to subtract 21, as you can see from his attempt to solve this.   ...wait, that would change 42 into 21, not 15?!

Comment: @ikegami 42 - 21 = 21. Edit: you caught it.

Comment: @ikegami Good point. The IP address I am dealing with doesn't have any zeroes in it.

Comment: Also, the 42 to 15, and 21 are all arbitrary, sorry for the confusion. The point I was trying to make is I want to subtract _some_ number from the one matched

Comment: You want to subtract some number from the first number in the line, and then replace that number with the result of the subtraction?

Comment: Ah, so it looks like you want to remove the protocol and hostname from the URL, then change the number to the left of the colon to be the length of the new string (excluding quotes), correct?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot You got it. This is a serialized PHP object so to modify the string I also need to modify the length count, and the modification I want to do is remove the https://ipaddr/ and leave the rest of the request URL. In this case, the length of https://ipaddr/ in my actual data is 21. I'll edit a bit more detail in

Comment: The less hacky approach would be to deserialize the data, modify the value, serialize the data, and update the row. Is that not an option?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [PHP::Serialization](https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP::Serialization).

Comment: Why does 21 - 21 equal 4?

Comment: Why is this question being down voted with no explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is this:

```
perl -pe 's{^(\d+)(:")(https://[\d.]+/)}{ ($1 - length($3)) . $2 }e' file
```

The key is the `e` modifier which evaluates the code in replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v FS="[:\"/]" '/[0-9]+:"https:\/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\// 
{print $1-17 ":\"" $(NF-1) "\"" }' file
4:"blah"
```